# Subtract value from lists when matching element is found

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class ScenarioResults
{
     public string ProductSubType { get; set; }

     public string SubBook { get; set; }

     public decimal? ScenarioValue { get; set; }
}
```

I have two lists of "ScenarioResults" objects.
I need to get a new list with values which are difference of scenariovalue from both lists.

subtraction criteria :

1. if productsubtype, subbook match for an object in both lists, subtract the scenariovalue in both.
2. if match is not found in first list, get first list object
3. if match is not found in second list, get -second list object

StartResults and EndResults are the two lists i have. I'm adding the results to Results list
I wrote the following code and it works:

```
var results = new List<ScenarioResults>();
foreach (var endResult in resultsEnd)
{
    var result = ScenarioResults.Clone(endResult);
    var startResult = resultsStart.FirstOrDefault(x.SubBook == result.SubBook && x.ProductSubType == result.ProductSubType);

    if (startResult == null)
    {
        result.ScenarioValue = endResult.ScenarioValue;
        results.Add(result);
    }
    else
    {
        result.ScenarioValue = endResult.ScenarioValue - startResult.ScenarioValue;
        results.Add(result);
    }
}
foreach (var startResult in resultsStart)
{
    var result = ScenarioResults.Clone(startResult);
    var endResult = resultsEnd.Any(x.SubBook == result.SubBook && x.ProductSubType == result.ProductSubType);
    if (!endResult)
    {
        result.ScenarioValue = -startResult.ScenarioValue;
        results.Add(result);
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to approach this? 
How to improve the performance of this?

Comment: Are you looking for [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Except doesn't subtract the value right? it just compares objects and returns non-matching ones of the first.

Comment: Yes, correct. I've probably misread the question, sorry.

Comment: Do you expect to see multiple values for the same `SubBook, ProductSubType` pair? In other words, could I use `SingleOrDefault` in place of `FirstOrDefault` and expect the code to not break?

Comment: Yes.. singleordefault should work the same. I'm grouping them in sql proc.

Comment: What should be result if `ScenarioValue` is `null`? Should be then treated as 0?

Comment: yes.. if it's null, should be treated as 0

Comment: Ok, I will update the answer then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify and speed up the code if you group both collections by a combination key that you use in your searches, i.e. `{SubBook, ProductSubType}`

```
var startDict = resultsStart
    .GroupBy(r => new {r.SubBook, r.ProductSubType})
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
var endDict = resultsEnd
    .GroupBy(r => new {r.SubBook, r.ProductSubType})
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First());
foreach (var key in startDict.Keys.Union(endDict.Keys)) {
    var hasStart = startDict.TryGetValue(key, out var start);
    var hasEnd = endDict.TryGetValue(key, out var end);
    if (hasStart && hasEnd) {
        ... // Construct the difference with subtraction
    } else if (hasStart) {
        ... // Construct the difference where only the start is present
    } else if (hasEnd) {
        ... // Construct the difference where only the end is present
    }
}
```

This solution is O(S+E) because of hash look-ups, while the original solution is O(S*E) because of nested linear searches.

Comment: This is ridiculous in terms of performance. My original search took 15 sec for my dataset where as your solution took 0.2 sec. Thanks a bunch. I really need to study DS and algo.!

Answer (score 1):

With pure LINQ :). This is just a showcase maybe has to be tweaked a bit but still can do the trick. Just to show an idea.

```
List<ScenarioResults> a = new List<ScenarioResults> { new ScenarioResults { ProductSubType = "1", SubBook = "1", ScenarioValue = 10}, new ScenarioResults { ProductSubType = "2", SubBook = "2", ScenarioValue = 10 } };
List<ScenarioResults> b = new List<ScenarioResults> { new ScenarioResults { ProductSubType = "2", SubBook = "2", ScenarioValue = 10 }, new ScenarioResults { ProductSubType = "3", SubBook = "3", ScenarioValue = 10 } };

List<ScenarioResults> result = a.Concat(b.Select(_ => new ScenarioResults { ProductSubType = _.ProductSubType, SubBook = _.SubBook, ScenarioValue = -_.ScenarioValue ?? 0}))
    .GroupBy(x => new {x.ProductSubType, x.SubBook})                  
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(_ => new ScenarioResults { ProductSubType = _.ProductSubType, SubBook = _.SubBook, ScenarioValue = (g.First().ScenarioValue ?? 0) + g.Skip(1).Sum(v => v.ScenarioValue)}))
    .Distinct(new EqualityComparer())
    .ToList();
```

where `EqualityComparer` is something like this:

```
public class EqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ScenarioResults>
{
    public bool Equals(ScenarioResults x, ScenarioResults y)
    {
        return x.ProductSubType == y.ProductSubType && x.SubBook == y.SubBook;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ScenarioResults obj)
    {
        return obj.ProductSubType.GetHashCode() ^ obj.SubBook.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `.Select(_ => _)` line?
How are the `ScenarioValue`'s calculated here, your test data made them all the same?

Comment: `Select(_=>_)` unfurl `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>` to `IEnumerable<T>`. The value is calculated within the `SelectMany` together with the `Concat` where the second list values are negated...

Comment: The values are not the same if you looked at the test data you have 2 as the same element 1 is only in a and 3 is only in b... {1, 10}{2, 0}{3, -10}

Comment: Given the SelectMany's type signature  and that it is Flatten/Collect in other languages  it still *looks like* it would produce IEnumerable<T> not `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`. Put it into VS2017 and as expected `Select(_=>_)` makes no difference to result.

Comment: Hmmm I see, I made then a mistake. Will edit answer. Thanks.

Comment: I see the ScenarioValue calcs now! me bad, problem reading such long lines in this browser, (I try to make my code be more readable within the available window). However the calc logic does not look correct. I really think that if this solution were done correctly it would be better than the preferred answered.

Comment: Cant edit previous comment. Went through it more on the IDE and it does look correct and very smart. +1